# how to select shortest path for browsing client

Tags: php, perl, routes, cgi

Is there a library (in PHP/PERL) that can calculate the shortest path for `/` from a browsing client to a list of possible ip addresses of servers, let's say there are three?

I looked in the *[BGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) algorithms* and it looks a bit too complex for what I am asking, perhaps just something that you feed it an array of server ip addresses and the client ip address (`REMOTE_ADDR`) and it comes back with the lengths and or the shortest path?

Would like to get:

1. Number of Hops
2. Ping time

And develop a bit of logic as to which to pick as the best path.

Comment: How would you define shortest path? Closest geographic relation? Shortest number of router hops? Lowest ping response? There's good reasons why BGP gets complicated.

Comment: well I would like to start with shortest number of router hops and then perhaps work in the ping response or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that what you've got is geographically distributed servers and are trying to redirect a client to optimise for latency?

I'd suggest that what you want is [`Net::Ping`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Ping.html) and  compare the relative results. Route length/topology etc. is very hard to manage effectively, which is why BGP is complicated. So don't even try, let your ISP worry about it.

Comment: yeah, this might be the end of the discussion actually, I will test with Net::Ping and report back, thanks, I had forgotten about that one!